# Oracle distinct on single column returning row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an api endpoint that accepts distinct arguments for filtering on specific columns. For this reason I'm trying to build a query that is easy to add arbitrary filters to the base query. For some reason if I use:

```
SELECT "MY_VIEW".* 
FROM   "MY_VIEW" 
    -- Distinct on ID filter
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT Max(ID) 
    FROM  "MY_VIEW" 
    GROUP  BY ID) 
    -- Other arbitrary filters...
ORDER  BY "MY_VIEW"."NAME" DESC
```

I get terrible performance so I started using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "MY_VIEW"
     -- Distinct on ID filter
     LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT
        FIRST_VALUE("MY_VIEW"."ID")
          OVER(PARTITION BY "MY_VIEW"."UNIQUE_ID") as DISTINCT_ID 
        FROM  "MY_VIEW"
    ) d ON d.DISTINCT_ID = "MY_VIEW"."ID"
    -- Other arbitrary filters...
    ORDER  BY "MY_VIEW"."NAME" DESC
)
```

However when I left join it discards the distinct filter.

Also I can't use rowid because it is a view.

The view is a versioned table.

***Index Info***

**UNIQUENESS** | **STATUS** | **INDEX_TYPE** | **TEMPORARY** | **PARTITIONED** | **JOIN_INDEX** | **COLUMNS**

NONUNIQUE | VALID | NORMAL | N | NO | NO | *ID*

UNIQUE    | VALID | NORMAL | N | NO | NO | *UNIQUE_ID*

NONUNIQUE | VALID | DOMAIN | N | NO | NO | *NAME*

Comment: Questions about performance should alteast include `CREATE TABLE/VIEW` structures and a query plan.. Without this information the question is pretty much unclear..

Comment: The query plan isn't correct and I don't have access to get the sql_id for a running query.

Comment: Well atleast provide us with table/view structures where indexes are visible..

Comment: If you haven't acccess then ask people who have the access. Without looking at the plan, the table structure and indices it is impossible to tune this query. I'am vote to close this question as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a "comment" so I will post this as an "answer." Your first example is:

```
SELECT "MY_VIEW".* 
FROM   "MY_VIEW" 
    -- Distinct on ID filter
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT Max(ID) 
    FROM  "MY_VIEW" 
    GROUP  BY ID) 
    -- Other arbitrary filters...
ORDER  BY "MY_VIEW"."NAME" DESC
```

But do you realize that the "GROUP BY ID" clause negates the effect of the MAX() function on ID? In other words, you will get all the rows and the MAX will be computed on each row's ID, returning . . . that row's ID. Perhaps try:

```
SELECT "MY_VIEW".* 
FROM   "MY_VIEW" 
    -- Distinct on ID filter
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT Max(ID) 
    FROM  "MY_VIEW") 
    -- Other arbitrary filters...
ORDER  BY "MY_VIEW"."NAME" DESC
```